# Moving member to a different group changes group permissions: Is this a bug?

Tags: members, bug

I just created a new EE member group, then moved a member from group 2 into the new group, and suddenly the permissions for group 2 - the old group - have been changed. That group is no longer allowed to post into any channel.

Anyone ever seen this? Is this a bug?

Comment: What version of EE are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like it could be related to this bug:

"[Channel posting privileges being removed from member groups](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18234)"

Comment: Wow, what a huge bug. Yes, that seems to be my issue. The posted fix resolved it.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this bug has been fixed in 2.5.4 -http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-5-4